# SQL Query - stuck on the following scenario:

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does anyone have an idea of how to deal this:

My scenario is I have a `CustomerTable, OrderTable, ItemsTable and DeliveryTable`

a Customer can make many orders
an order can contain many items

however this is where the problem is, if i have lets say 1 item, with the quantity of `20..` i receive `15` of these into stock and want to send `15/20` to the customer. currently i can assign the `DeliveryID` to the individual item but that contains all `20`.

*So my question is do i need a middle table or is there an obvious approach i am missing here?*

Comment: Something in the delivery table to indicate the number of items delivered would help.

Comment: If you're rolling items -> orders and orders -> customers, couldn't you just carry the number ordered of the item?  I'm not sure exactly what you're getting at here. Do you want your inventory to update and show that, in the example above, there are 5 left?

Comment: Why not track every item individually? Currently your `Items`-table seems to contain both `ItemTypes` and `Items` I would suggest to seperate that (1:n-relation between items and itemTypes), that way you can also have a serial number attached for example and use `Items`-table for inventory.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste: That's makes eminent sense for automobiles, and is ridiculous for pencil cases. You have no basis (yet) for assuming one exists rather than he other.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens true, thats why I put the `why` in there ;)

Comment: cheers guys for the input... got something to aim at now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A Customer can have multiple Orders
- An order can have multiple orderlines (items)
- An orderline can have multiple deliverylines
- A delivery can have multiple deliverylines(maybe even of different
  orders)

You can then lookup if a orderline is completed by fetching all deliverylines.

```
Select 
    ( select name from items where id = ol.itemid ) as itemname, 
    ol.quantity as quantity_ordered,
    ( select sum(quantity) from deliverylines dl where dl.olid = ol.id ) as quantity_delivered
from orderlines ol 
where orderid = <id>;
```

Comment: what kind of columns do i need to include in the deliveryline as this is the table i am missing... as it currently stands my orderline contains:

QuantityOrdered
QuantityRecieved
QuantitySent

Comment: didn't use the query but the relationships and the DeliveryLine worked a treat, thanks